# If n > 3 and (n + 1) is a square, is there any n that is a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring

I am looking at properties of squares and came about this property. I am investigating   the difference of squares in relation to primes.

Comment: I meant to say is there any n which is prime? I cannot find a prime that has this properties. How can I edit this?

Comment: $n+1 = a^2 \iff n = a^2 - 1 = (a-1)(a+1)$.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a prime n and this is a difference of square. I meant to ask Is n a composite?

Answer (score 9):

> Does there exist a prime of the form $a^2-1$ when $a^2-1>3$?

No, because $$a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$$ and both $a-1$ and $a+1$ are non-trivial factors.

Comment: Thanks what I meant is say an integer m = n + 1 and m is a square. Is there any n that will meet this? Sorry but I'm not asking if there is prime of the form of mentioned, of course fermat primes (5 and 17) are examples of your forms.

Comment: That's what I mean.  Here $n=a^2-1$ so $m=a^2$ which is a square.  Fermat Primes are of the form $2^n+1$ (Mersenne Primes are of the form $2^n-1$), so these are different.

Comment: you are right. It is simply the difference of square hence n factors are (a + 1) and (a - 1). Thanks.